# EVR/VMR9 video motion artifacts

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card, visual-artifacts, mpeg2

I have an issue that has been bugging me for months and despite several hours-long web searches I've come up with nothing, partly because I can't even find the right search terms. I'll try to explain the effect, and I'm hoping it will ring a bell with someone.

Ideally I would like a way to get rid of the effect altogether, but even a name for the effect that will give me something to work with would be a very good start.

What I'm seeing is different areas of videos moving at slightly different rates - i.e. they shift slightly relative to one another when they should be in perfect sync.

At this point I should say I know exactly what combing and tearing are, and it's nothing like either effect.

I notice it most often on people's faces, where their head will be moving slightly (as they talk for example) and it will be like some skin texture or feature like a mole won't move, or will move slightly out of step with the face outline. Or in a brick wall with a slightly unsteady camera, the mortar lines will move slightly out of step with the texture of the bricks.

I watch almost exclusively live/recorded DVB-S MPEG2 content. I see the same effect with different MPEG2 decoders (MS, LAV, Mainconcept...) and on different players (DVBViewer, Windows Media Player, MPC-HC at least). The effect is visible when using VMR9 and EVR, but *not* when using "Overlay Mixer" (unfortunately the latter has other problems for me and is therefore not a solution). So I'm wondering if it's something to do with smoothing/interpolation being applied by the more modern renderers (the video looks slightly more pixelly through overlay mixer), or potentially something that's been handed off to the GPU.

Windows 7 64-bit, initially noticed using the integrated graphics on my Celeron G1840 and then bought a cheap ATI 5450 card, hoping that would resolve it, but no dice.

It's got to the point where I'm constantly watching out for it, to the extent that I caught myself looking for it in someone's face in real life recently (I actually nearly believed I could see it for a second!) so this is clearly starting to affect my sanity.

Anyone know what might be going on?

**UPDATE:** I dug out my old ATI HD3450 and it doesn't happen on that. So I connected a second display to the integrated graphics, and observed that if I play the video on the ATI card but have part of the window extended onto the integrated display, the effect is not visible on either display. Conversely, if the video is playing on the integrated display but part of the window is on the ATI display, the effect *is* visible on *both* displays. I can also see a significant difference in the colour balance etc. depending (presumably) on which GPU is handling the bulk of the rendering (or possibly decoding?). I'm leaning towards thinking it's some aspect of dxva2 which is not available on the older ATI card, and wondering if might be any way of identifying what it is and somehow disabling it in the pipeline of the integrated graphics and/or newer card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be caused by noise reduction (de-noise).

I can't find an option to disable the noise reduction in the Intel integrated graphics, but after installing the latest AMD Catalyst control panel and driver for the discrete card, I can disable it under:

```
Start->Video->Quality->De-noise
```

Once this is switched off, the effect is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many many configurations, the following combination seems to work:

- Use Intel HD integrated GPU
- Use LAV filter for decoding
- In LAV filter settings -> Hardware Decoder to use, choose "Intel QuickSync"
- Under Hardware/GPU Deinterlacing (CUVID/QS Only), Select "Enable Adaptive HW Deinterlacing"
- For Output Mode select 50p/60p (Video)
- Select High-Quality Processing (in my case I can't uncheck this option)

It's not clear to me whether it's actually something to do with deinterlacing that's fixing the issue, or whether selecting the option modifies the pipeline in such a way as to avoid the problem (e.g. that hardwired "High-Quality Processing" option), but at least it is now working.

Also note that the option is not available on the ATI/AMD cards as they don't support CUVID or QuickSync. In my case, that's fine as I only bought the discrete card to try to resolve the issue.